# terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException .I have a Signal-Sigbrt error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

[image: Error image]
I Followed other instructions but I don't know what's wrong. Check connections but everything seems alright.

This is my connections, perfectly fine:
[image: Storyboard image]

Same thing:

[image: View connections]

Comment: Show the whole error message.

Comment: Do not post screenshot of your error. Copy/Paste as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception shows that you are attempting to store something in `NSUserDefaults` that cannot be stored there.  You can only store:

`NSArray`, `NSData`, `NSDictionary`, `NSNumber` and `NSString`.

This is happening in `[ViewController6 registerNewUser]`, somewhere.

That's all I can tell you without seeing the code, but I expect you are attempting to store a custom object that represents a user account, rather than the properties of this object.

Comment: Ok, Thank you! Appreciate it.

Comment: The exception explicitly states that he's trying to store a UITextField.  I assume he meant to store the `text` property.